# How to define operator overloading for STL(C++).

Tags: c++, stl

I have a question related to operator overloading, and it is easy to define a class as well as its operator overloading function as the following codes illustrate:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > ARRAY; 


class ABC
{
public:
    ABC():a(0)
    {
    };
    int a;
    ABC& operator = (int value)
    {
        a = value;
        return *this;
    }
    ABC(int value)
    {
        a = value;

    }
};


void obtain_priority_array(const std::vector<double> &weighting, const ABC &priority_array=NULL)
{

}

int main()
{
    vector<double> weighting;
    weighting.push_back(0.8);
    weighting.push_back(0.9);
    weighting.push_back(0.6);
    weighting.push_back(0.3);
    weighting.push_back(0.5);

    ABC test;
    obtain_priority_array(weighting, test);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, `class ABC` redefined `operator =` so that the function  `void obtain_priority_array(const std::vector<double> &weighting, const ABC &priority_array=NULL)` can have a default argument `const ABC &priority_array=NULL`. My question is if the last parameter in the function comes from STL, for example, `const std::vector<int> &priority_array=NULL`, how can we redefine `operator =`.  Thanks!

EDIT:
**void obtain_priority_array(const std::vector &weighting, `const std::vector<int> &sample=NULL`)** failed!

Comment: Why don't you change your function to takes pointers, instead of references? If you want to  pass only `NULL` as default parameter.

Comment: By the way, `operator=` is not being called for the default argument. The constructor taking an int is: http://liveworkspace.org/code/84813303faa93e2b1359fa90c21adba8

Comment: References were designed to avoid being NULL. Trying to pass NULL as a reference seems to be a bad code conception.

Comment: @chris Yes, then my question is for STL components, how can I define a constructor for STL vector?

Comment: @feelfree, Look at this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector. The only constructor that can take `NULL` is explicit, so you'd need something along the lines of `const std::vector<int> &priority_array = std::vector<int>(NULL)`, which translates to an empty vector. If it should translate to no vector, you must use a pointer.

Comment: @chris Thanks, it works. Could you answer this question? I think you have given me the right answer.

Comment: @chris There is no vector constructor that can take a null pointer. `std::vector<int>(nullptr)` [will not compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/82c8042d4ba62b90de9fe59d7994a0b9). `std::vector<int>(NULL)` will compile only because `NULL` is `0`.

Comment: @Prætorian, I realize that. I kind of tried to point it out a little with the empty vector part thrown in. I was a bit more explicit in my answer.

Comment: @chris Good to see an answer from you, instead of comments only :-). Even in the answer though, there's no reason for the argument, just default constructing the vector is enough. But I'm glad you replaced the `NULL` with `0`, since the former is confusing.

Comment: @Prætorian, I guess, but I was keeping similar syntax to what the OP was providing to it right now, and it is only one extra character. I don't think you can default it without the whole extra `std::vector<int>` in there, can you? Maybe it could be a different use for `default`. `const std::vector<int> & = default` has a nice ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misconceptions start with the proposal to add `operator=` to allow for a default argument of that type. In your example, it is not `operator=` being called, but `ABC(int)`.

The reason your code isn't being accepted when using `std::vector` is that `NULL` translates to 0 (at least it does almost all of the time you'll see it), and the only constructor of `std::vector` that can take 0, the one taking a count of how many items, is marked explicit.

To fix the immediate problem, the syntax could be changed to:

```
const std::vector<int> &priority_array = std::vector<int>(0)
```

However, this introduces different semantics. By your use of `NULL`, it looks like you were expecting it to represent no vector. This version will provide an empty vector for use if none is given. It will *not* be no vector at all. If you want that distinction, you should use boost's optional library, or a simple pointer, as references are not the right tool.

Answer (score 3):

References cannot be `NULL`, your problem has nothing to do with operator overloading. If you want to be able to handle `NULL` as the default value, switch the parameter type from *reference* to *pointer*.

```
void obtain_priority_array( const std::vector<double>& weighting, 
                            const ABC *priority_array = NULL)
{
  if( priority_array == NULL ) {
    // blah
  } else {
    // more blah
  }
}
```

Another option is to use something like [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) to represent the optional parameter.

```
typedef boost::optional<ABC> maybe_ABC;
void obtain_priority_array( const std::vector<double>& weighting, 
                            const maybe_ABC& priority_array = maybe_ABC() )
{
  if( !priority_array ) {
    // blah
  } else {
    // more blah
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `=` to create a reference, you're not calling `operator=` at all. You're initializing the reference.

Instead of using `NULL` you can create a static instance of the class to represent a null value.

```
static const ABC ABC_NULL;

void obtain_priority_array(const std::vector<double> &weighting, const ABC &priority_array=ABC_NULL)
{
    if (&priority_array == &ABC_NULL) // the default was used
```

Of course it would be easier to just use a pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. The problem now I face is that if **std::vector<int> priority_array** is an argument of the function obtain_priority_array, and the function expects a default constructor for **std::vector<int> priority_array**, what should I do?

Comment: @chris has given me the right answer: const std::vector<int> &priority_array = std::vector<int>(NULL). Thanks anyway!